# La varible opcion coge un valor dentro del codigo de manera anormal

Tags: java

me gustaria que alguien que entienda mas de Java que yo me pudiera explicar porque me ocurre esto en el codigo, resulta que cuando intento finalizar el programa dandole a opcion valor 0 despues de haber introducido una opcion difirente a 0 primero, mi codigo se salta el bucle como deberia y luego por alguna parte del codigo coge que opcion tiene valor 1 y se vuelve a poner en funcionamiento el bulce.
He repasado el codigo con la opcion de debug de Visual Studio un millon de veces y no veo ningun fallo aparente, pero aun asi sigue sacando un valor de 1 para opcion, salta de la linea 40 a la linea 62, y de ahi salta a la linea 32 que equivale con `}else if(opcion>1&&comprobante==true){`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ejercicio21 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random alea = new Random();
        int comodin=alea.nextInt(51);
        int[] numeros=new int[comodin];
        boolean comprobante=false;
        menu(numeros,comprobante);
    }
    public static void menu(int[] p,boolean comprobante){
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcion;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("MENÚ PRINCIPAL\n==============\n1.-Rellenar array.\n2.-Visualizar contenido del array\n3.-Visualizar contenido par.\n4.-Visualizar contenido múltiplo de 3\n0.-Salir del menú.\nSelecciona una opción: ");
        opcion=lector.nextInt();
        lector.nextLine();
        while(opcion<0||opcion>4){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Introduce una opcicon valida entre 0 y 4\nSelecciona una opción: ");
            opcion=lector.nextInt();
            lector.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
        while(opcion!=0){
            if(opcion==1&&comprobante==true){
                comprobante=false;
            }
            if(opcion==1&&comprobante==false){
                crearArray(p);
            }else if(opcion>1&&comprobante==true){
                control(opcion,p);
            }else if(opcion>1&&comprobante==false){
                System.out.println("La array no esta llena, primero rellene la array");
                menu(p,comprobante);
            }
        }
            System.out.println("-------------FIN DEL PROGRAMA--------------");
    }
    public static void control(int opcion,int[] numeros){
        switch(opcion){
            case 2:
                visualizarArray(numeros);
            break;
            case 3:
                visualizarParell(numeros);
            break;
            case 4:
                visualizarMultiple3(numeros);
            break;
        }
    }
    public static void crearArray(int[] vector){//rellena el array con números aleatorios del 0 al 50.
        Random alea = new Random();
        boolean comprobante;
        for(int i=0;i<vector.length;i++){
            vector[i]=alea.nextInt(20-0+1);
        }
        comprobante=true;
        menu(vector,comprobante);
    }
    public static void visualizarArray(int[] vector){//visualiza todo el contenido del array.
        boolean comprobante;
        comprobante=true;
        for(int i=0;i<vector.length;i++){
            if(i%4==0){
                System.out.println();
            }else{
                System.out.print(vector[i]+"\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        menu(vector,comprobante);
    }
    public static void visualizarParell(int[] vector){//muestra la posición y el contenido de los elementos que tienen valor par.
        boolean comprobante;
        comprobante=true;
        for(int i=0;i<vector.length;i++){
            if(vector[i]%2==0){
                System.out.println("Posicion "+i+"="+vector[i]);
            }
        }               
        System.out.println();
        menu(vector,comprobante);
    }
    public static void visualizarMultiple3(int[] vector){//muestra la posición y el contenido de los elementos que son múltiplo de 3.
        boolean comprobante;
        comprobante=true;
        for(int i=0;i<vector.length;i++){
            if(vector[i]%3==0){
                System.out.println("Posicion "+i+"="+vector[i]+"\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        menu(vector,comprobante);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de tu método *menu* tienes:

```
if(opcion>1&&comprobante==false){
   System.out.println("La array no esta llena, primero rellene la array");
   menu(p, comprobante);
}
```

Es decir, llamas al método *menu* **otra vez**(la palabra técnica es *recursión*). Esta nueva invocación creará sus propias variables locales (que, aunque tengan el mismo nombre, no comparten el valor de las variables locales de las invocaciones anteriores).

Así que cuando hagas `opcion == 0`, saldrás del bucle y de la invocación del método *menu*. Pero como esa invocación la has hecho desde el propio método, volverás al punto en el que invocaste el método y seguirás dentro del bucle de la invocación anterior.

Como puede ser un poco lioso de ver, te aconsejo que añadas al método un parámetro numérico y que, al invocarlo, le añadas uno al valor recibido. Si imprimes esos valores verás que vas entrando y saliendo de los distintos niveles de invocación. Algo como

```
public static void menu(int[] p, boolean comprobante, int nivel){
   ...
   if(opcion>1&&comprobante==false){
     System.out.println("La array no esta llena, primero rellene la array");
     menu(p, comprobante, nivel + 1);
   }
```

Además, tu segundo bucle no tiene sentido. Sales de él cuando `opcion == 0`, pero en ningún sitio modificas `opcion`. Si se entra, no hay forma de salir de ese bucle.

La solución es no usar recursión, sino un bucle principal bien organizado. La idea sería:

```
mientras no(opcion == salir) {
   opcion = leerEntrada();
   hacerAccion(opcion);
}
```

En *leerEntrada()* puedes entrar en un bucle interno hasta que te den un valor válido (que es lo que haces en tu primer bucle).